# jQuery datetime picker only working for the first time

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I am using a datetimepicker function of jQuery to populate a calendar where the user can select the date and time. As I need that in a table I am using it inside a `td` tag. But I can find that the calendar is shown only for the first time and the next time the user clicks on it the calendar is not opening. I cannot see any errors in my console too. Below is my code:

```
<td ng-show="on-certain-condition" class = "date customTimeFrom">
    <input type="text" class="input-custom-box" ng-model="dateAndTime" id="date" style="margin: 7px 0px 6px 22px;" />
</td>
<script>
$(function(){ 
var dateTimePickerAttr = {  
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true, 
    todayBtn: true, 
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
};
    $('#date').datetimepicker(dateTimePickerAttr);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's `dateTimePickerAttr`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I got the problem. I was creating a new instance of my modal window without destroying the previous one. So there was a problem with the id attribute I changed it to class and tried it worked. But i don't know whether its the correct way to do it... I request a suggestion for it.